# Delete global variables nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a node app that when it's started makes an object.

```
function my_object(){

}

my_object.prototype.say_lol = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('lol');
    }, 1000);
};


var ping = new my_object();

ping.say_lol();

process.on( 'SIGINT', function() {

    delete global.ping; // Please?


    // pseudo code to go update something in the database or whatever
    setTimeout(function(){
        process.exit();
    }, 4000);

});
```

When it ends I need to delete that object to prevent it from firing lol over and over while the timeout is pending. Is there any elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Please add more info about what problem you are trying to solve. have you tried `delete ping`? also `process.exit()` should stop code execution; I am pretty sure that no further pending `setTimeout` callbacks are executed

Comment: I've updated the example to make it a little more understandable why you would want to do this. I've tried `delete ping` but to no success.

Comment: Title completely misrepresents the question. Deleting the object doesn't fix the problem so no acceptable answer will ever match the title.

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture the id of what setTimeOut returns and then clear it if you don't want to fire at a later point.

```
my_object.prototype.say_lol = function() {
    return (setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('lol');
    }, 1000));
};

var ping = new my_object();
var timeOutId = ping.say_lol();

process.on( 'SIGINT', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeOutId);
    process.exit();
});
```

If the event is not fired yet, it will be cancelled. If its already fired, it fails silenty.

Comment: I don't want to end the timeout I want to delete the entire object. There are a bunch of other things inside that function in my project that are ticking over. I need to drop the whole thing.

Comment: You don't normally "delete" things in JavaScript. You just undo whatever you did, stop referencing them and they go away. `clearTimeout()` is the correct way of stopping your timer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to stop the callback from firing. My approach would be to keep track of `ping`'s state in another variable and use an `if` statement wrapping whatever chunk of code fires the unwanted callbacks.

```
function my_object(){ };
var stillHere = true;

my_object.prototype.say_lol = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(stillHere){  
      console.log('lol');
    }
  }, 2000);
};

var ping = new my_object();
ping.say_lol();

process.on( 'SIGINT', function() {
  delete global.ping; // Please?
  stillHere = false;
  setTimeout(function(){
    process.exit();
  }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: RE: my deleted answer. You where right. It deletes the variable but the listener remains.

Answer (score 0):

Although I understand it's not a true answer, but this solved my issue. I ran the node process in a cluster and killed off any children that I wanted to delete. This worked in my instance as the children were performing endless tasks and when I needed them to be stopped that was the only logical way I could abort them.